# Can large bike size will be solved by replacing the crank arm with a longer length?

Tags: road-bike, crankset, bike-fit, carbon, geometry

I recently bought a carbon fiber bike and the size is a bit big, it's sava phantom3.0 56cm ,but I love the bike and don't want to wait too long for small size bike, would a longer crank arm be a good option?

Comment: You'd want to use smaller cranks, not larger, ignoring whether it's a good idea or not.

Comment: what's your reasoning behind this?

Comment: *the size is a bit big* **Why** do you think it's "a bit big"?  "Can't reach to pedals for a full pedal stroke even with the saddle as low as it can go" usually means "a **LOT** big", not "a bit big".  And if that's the problem, longer crank arms will make it worse because the pedals will be *farther* away from the saddle at the bottom of the pedal stroke.

Answer (score 6):

The frame size of the bicycle is designed according to the rider's height and inseam length to ensure a suitable and comfortable pedaling. Swapping the crank arms to shorter or longer ones can adjust pedal travel a bit, but it probably won't solve the problem of a bike that's too big or too small for a rider.

I found the specs for your [sava phantom3.0](https://savadeck-bike.com/products/savadeck-phantom-3-0-carbon-road-bike-ultegra-r8000), its geometry data will make it clearer

If the frame size of the bike is too large for the rider, it can cause discomfort, loss of control, and affect the rider's performance. In this case it is usually recommended to replace the oversized frame with a suitable one.

However, if the bike's frame is reasonably close to the rider's stature, adjusting the seat height and handlebar position may provide a more comfortable and efficient fit. A professional bike fit session with an experienced bike fitter or a local bike shop will help you fine-tune the fit of your bike and ensure optimum performance and comfort.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe - a longer crank arm lets your foot go lower, permitting the saddle to be a little lower.

But it also forces your opposite foot to move higher to complete the circle, and that may not be comfortable.

Longer crank arms obviously won't do anything for reach either, and you also have an increased risk of pedal strike while riding.

Given you will ride this bike for possibly decades, don't compromise now with the wrong size.  Have patience and get the right fit.

Comment: Actually, if you're aged under 18 then there's a fair chance you're still growing, and in that case buying slightly larger may be a good idea; you'd literally grow into it.